# How can I solve my multithreading feature?

Tags: java, multithreading

My code:

```java
public class Main {
    static int counter = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<>();
        IntStream.range(0, 5).forEach(index -> threads.add(new Thread(() -> new Main().incrementCounter())));
        threads.forEach(Thread::start);
        while (threads.stream().filter(Thread::isAlive).findAny().isPresent()) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10);
                System.out.println("intermediate output " + counter);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Final output " + counter);
    }

    public synchronized void incrementCounter() {
        IntStream.range(0, 1000).forEach(index1 -> counter++);
    }
}
```

I can't synchronize this feature to get its right result.

How can I synchronize it and get right solution?

Comment: See [mcve]. What do you EXPECT to be the "right" solution, and what happens instead? er.

Comment: Ah, yes, right: each Thread has its OWN new Main object. So the `synchronized` is meaningless, because it does NOT prevent the different objects to call "their" method. Solutions would be: A) use 1 Main object, not 5 or B) make the increment method static or C) dont use an `int` counter but AtomicInteger for example.

Comment: Also, It makes little sense for the top-level method of any thread to be `synchronized`. If it's`synchronized` then that prevents the thread, in its entirety, from running concurrently with any other thread that synchronizes on the same object. GhostCat told you why `synchronized` isn't working in your example: Each thread synchronizes on a different object. But, if you "fix" it by having them all synchronize on the same object, then the threads will run sequentially (one-by-one) instead of running concurrently, and that _completely_ defeats the purpose of using threads.

Comment: @GhostCat Thank you! All provided options work fine!

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by comments, don't use an `int` when updating/incrementing a variable across multiple threads (that is not atomic), use an [`AtomicInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) instead to avoid race conditions. Also no need to make the `incrementCounter` method synchronized as the atomicity is enough to make it thread-safe:

```
static AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();

public synchronized void incrementCounter() {
    IntStream.range(0, 1000).forEach(index1 -> counter.incrementAndGet());
}
```